# Transposing a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

Have a situation where I've got

```
  > sample_df <- data.frame(id = c(14129, 29102, 2191, 2192, 1912)
                        , color = c("blue", "red", "green", "purple", "blue")
                        , day = c("monday", "wednesday", "thursday", "monday", "tuesday")
                        , happy = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1))

  > sample_df 
     id  color       day happy
  14129   blue    monday     1
  29102    red wednesday     1
   2191  green  thursday     1
   2192 purple    monday     1
   1912   blue   tuesday     1
```

want to be able to create a column that transposes the two columns to have something like:

```
> sample_df_2 <- data.frame(id = c(14129,14129, 29102,29102, 2191,2191, 2192,2192, 1912,1912)
                          , type = c("blue", "monday","red","wednesday","green","thursday","purple","monday","blue","tuesday")
                          , happy = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))

> sample_df_2
      id      type happy
   14129      blue     0
   14129    monday     1
   29102       red     0
   29102 wednesday     1
    2191     green     0
    2191  thursday     1
    2192    purple     0
    2192    monday     1
    1912      blue     0
    1912   tuesday     1
```

The idea about the last column is just to say, if we're dealing with a value pulled from the original `color` field then `happy` is automatically `0`, otherwise `1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `gather`ing into 'long' format, one option is to replace the values in 'happy' that corresponds to "color" in 'key' column as the negated value, `select` the columns of interest and `arrange` if neccessary

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(sample_df, key, type, color:day) %>%
    mutate(happy = case_when(key == "color" ~ as.numeric(!happy), TRUE ~ happy)) %>%
    select(-key) %>%
    arrange(id)
```

Comment: Thanks! Quick question, I keep getting this error back: `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: must be type double, not integer.` Any thoughts as I'm feeding gather only character types?

Comment: Fixed! Added `as.numeric` on the last `happy` on the second line

Comment: @S31 Based on your example, it is working fine for me.  May be in your original data, `happy` is `integer` class.  `case_when` is very particular about the `type`