# For each group, keep one row on column condition in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Building off of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52975714/transposing-a-dataframe/52975742?noredirect=1#comment92869774_52975742) question

I'm adding in the factor of time and duplicating id's by doing so:

```
sample_df <- data.frame(id = c(14129, 14129, 14129, 29102, 29102, 2191, 2191, 2191, 2191, 2192, 2192, 1912, 1912, 1912)
                        , date = c("2018-06-15 00:15:42","2018-10-08 12:44:44",
                                   "2018-07-09 18:14:58", "2018-06-15 00:15:40",
                                   "2018-06-15 00:19:42", "2018-10-15 08:17:47",
                                   "2018-09-29 10:16:34", "2018-07-09 18:28:25",
                                   "2018-07-09 18:28:25", "2018-07-09 18:20:32",
                                   "2018-08-30 13:06:45", "2018-10-08 11:32:55",
                                   "2018-10-05 11:32:55", "2018-10-08 09:09:56")
                        , color = c("blue", "blue", "green", "red", "red", "red", "green", "blue", "green", "purple", "blue", "blue", "red", "red")
                        , day = c("monday", "monday", "monday", "wednesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "thursday",
                                  "thursday", "thursday", "monday", "monday", "tuesday", "tuesday", "tuesday")
                        , happy = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1))


> sample_df
      id                date  color       day happy
1  14129 2018-06-15 00:15:42   blue    monday     1
2  14129 2018-10-08 12:44:44   blue    monday     0
3  14129 2018-07-09 18:14:58  green    monday     0
4  29102 2018-06-15 00:15:40    red wednesday     0
5  29102 2018-06-15 00:19:42    red wednesday     1
6   2191 2018-10-15 08:17:47    red  thursday     1
7   2191 2018-09-29 10:16:34  green  thursday     0
8   2191 2018-07-09 18:28:25   blue  thursday     1
9   2191 2018-07-09 18:28:25  green  thursday     0
10  2192 2018-07-09 18:20:32 purple    monday     0
11  2192 2018-08-30 13:06:45   blue    monday     1
12  1912 2018-10-08 11:32:55   blue   tuesday     0
13  1912 2018-10-05 11:32:55    red   tuesday     0
14  1912 2018-10-08 09:09:56    red   tuesday     1
```

Once that original dataframe is put through this code:

```
sample_df$date <- as.POSIXct(sample_df$date)

sample_df_2 <- sample_df %>% 
  gather(key, type, color:day) %>%
  mutate(happy = case_when(key == "color" ~ 0, TRUE ~ as.numeric(happy))) %>%
  select(-key) %>%
  arrange(id)

> sample_df_2
      id                date happy      type
1   1912 2018-10-08 11:32:55     0      blue
2   1912 2018-10-05 11:32:55     0       red
3   1912 2018-10-08 09:09:56     0       red
4   1912 2018-10-08 11:32:55     0   tuesday
5   1912 2018-10-05 11:32:55     0   tuesday
6   1912 2018-10-08 09:09:56     1   tuesday
7   2191 2018-10-15 08:17:47     0       red
8   2191 2018-09-29 10:16:34     0     green
9   2191 2018-07-09 18:28:25     0      blue
10  2191 2018-07-09 18:28:25     0     green
11  2191 2018-10-15 08:17:47     1  thursday
12  2191 2018-09-29 10:16:34     0  thursday
13  2191 2018-07-09 18:28:25     1  thursday
14  2191 2018-07-09 18:28:25     0  thursday
15  2192 2018-07-09 18:20:32     0    purple
16  2192 2018-08-30 13:06:45     0      blue
17  2192 2018-07-09 18:20:32     0    monday
18  2192 2018-08-30 13:06:45     1    monday
19 14129 2018-06-15 00:15:42     0      blue
20 14129 2018-10-08 12:44:44     0      blue
21 14129 2018-07-09 18:14:58     0     green
22 14129 2018-06-15 00:15:42     1    monday
23 14129 2018-10-08 12:44:44     0    monday
24 14129 2018-07-09 18:14:58     0    monday
25 29102 2018-06-15 00:15:40     0       red
26 29102 2018-06-15 00:19:42     0       red
27 29102 2018-06-15 00:15:40     0 wednesday
28 29102 2018-06-15 00:19:42     1 wednesday
```

you can see that `day` value gets duplicated for all the `dates` once it's gathered, ideally I would just like to have one row for `day` in each id grouping, and the corresponding `date` be the earliest `date` from each respective grouping. Tried to filter on `day`, and then slice out one row and inner join the original table - but that was a mess.

Desired output --

```
sample_df
      id                date happy      type
1   1912 2018-10-08 11:32:55     0      blue
2   1912 2018-10-05 11:32:55     0       red
3   1912 2018-10-08 09:09:56     0       red
4   1912 2018-10-05 11:32:55     0   tuesday
7   2191 2018-10-15 08:17:47     0       red
8   2191 2018-09-29 10:16:34     0     green
9   2191 2018-07-09 18:28:25     0      blue
10  2191 2018-07-09 18:28:25     0     green
15  2192 2018-07-09 18:20:32     0    purple
16  2192 2018-08-30 13:06:45     0      blue
17  2192 2018-07-09 18:28:25     0    monday
19 14129 2018-06-15 00:15:42     0      blue
20 14129 2018-10-08 12:44:44     0      blue
21 14129 2018-07-09 18:14:58     0     green
22 14129 2018-06-15 00:15:42     1    monday
25 29102 2018-06-15 00:15:40     0       red
26 29102 2018-06-15 00:19:42     0       red
27 29102 2018-06-15 00:15:40     1 wednesday
```

Comment: Can you please provide your expected output.

Comment: I find it really unclear what it is you are trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr::row_number()` we can select the first row in each (id,days) group after we flag them as 0's

```
library(dplyr)
sample_df_2 %>% mutate(Flag=if_else(type %in% c('blue','red','green','purple'),1,0))
            %>% group_by(id,Flag) %>% filter(Flag==1 | Flag==0 & row_number()==1) 
            %>% ungroup() %>% select(-Flag)
```

Comment: @S31 please check my answer, there are some differences in days time but I think you missed them while you copy and paste for the expected output.